# Bearing and Course Trigonometry Question

Tags: trigonometry

This is the question:

A jet flew 140 mi on a course of 196 degrees and then 120 mi on a course of 106 degrees then the jet return to its starting point via the shortest route possible. Find the total distance that the jet traveled.

I found the answer for this. It's this one:
http://ph.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110828043233AAVgQcy

Now I understand everything else, but my problem is why and how they used the given angles to confirm that it is a right triangle. I know this has something to do with theorems on parallel lines, but I just can't picture how. I will need an illustration to understand this. Thank you.  :)

Answer (score 1):

It's always good to draw a picture in these cases. A right angle is 90 degrees. So if you're traveling at 196 degrees, and you change to 106 degrees, you have made a change of 90 degrees; therefore you have turned at a right angle.

Answer (score 1):

Total is $444.39$.

Proof: From the second point, the jet traveled on an angle of $106$ so when you draw it, you will get a $90$ degree angle.
$$196-180=16$$
$$106-16-16=90$$
since opposite angles are the same.

Now using $H^2=A^2+O^2$:
$$H^2=19600+14400=34000$$
$$H=444.39$$